# On The Subject of The Odd One Out

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

<sup>(This is part of a series of puzzles written for [Timwi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1480/timwi?tab=profile) for a Secret Santa puzzle exchange, themed around various custom modules for the game *Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes*. No KTaNE knowledge is necessary for any of these puzzles except the final meta; each puzzle resolves to a single word or short phrase.)</sup>

---

## On The Subject of The Odd One Out

- AID AND ABET, CAT SCAN, HAIR TRIGGER, NINEVEH, SEES
- AFTEREFFECTS, FREEZER, NOCUOUS, VERTEX, WARFARE
- ALUMINOSILICATES, BELOVED, HIMALAYAN, INDIA INK, VERISIMILITUDE
- ANTHERS, DOUGLASS, FIREBAR, SLUMBER, THOUSAND
- BATHROBE, BRAZEN, CAROUSEL, ELLIPSIS, WEIGHTIEST
- CARBON COPY, CROSSTALK, PENNY DREADFUL, TROUSERS, TURN UP
- CARDIOID, LINNAEAN, NICOTINIC, PALEOETHNOLOGY, TOE OF FROG
- COMMENCEMENT, DETOURS, JASMINE, JOINT HEIRS, THIS
- CONSOLATE, CORRIGIBLE, NEATH, SENSICAL, WHELMED
- DAGGER, EVITATIVE, LOZENGE, PILCROW, TIE
- DEIFIED, KOOK, RIYAL ICON, PUT UP, RADAR
- DIE, ERT, GOOSE, SERAPH, SURGEON GENERAL
- HIGHLIGHTER, HOTHATCH, INDEPENDENT, PHENOMENON, SEVENTEENTH
- LABYRINTHINE, MOTHY, PATHED, THINNER, UNTHINKABLE

---

Hint:

> The answer is not any of the words in the puzzle.

Hint for "CARBON COPY" group:

> Think cryptically. The fact that each is two words / a compound is important, but not the only detail.

Comment: I don't know if this counts as partial so I just comment here: rot13(Jr arrq gb svaq gur bqq bar bhg sbe rnpu yvar: (3) VAQVNVAX - nygreangvat ibjry-pbafbanag (4) NAGUREF - cersvk/fhssvk jbeq vf zngrevny? (5) RYYVCFVF - arj jbeq jvgubhg fgnevat naq raqvat yrggre (8) PBZZRAPRZRAG - fhssvk vf cbffrfvir cebabha (9) PBEEVTVOYR - haqre- ? (11) EVLNYVPBA - cnyvaqebzr (13) ??? - fbzrguvat nobhg bppherapr bs yrggref.)

Comment: @athin I'm at all but 4 now, but I also don't know if it really counts as partial because I haven't figured out how to put it all together yet.  BTW rot13(Gur bqq jbeqf bhg nyy svg va ng yrnfg 1 naq hfhnyyl zber guna 2 bgure pngrtbel.)

Comment: @JS1 OwO that's great! I'm pretty sure yours can be counted as partial especially for your finding on the last sentence!

Comment: Building off of @athin’s work, some more observations/thoughts: rot13(1 (NVQ NAQ NORG) nyy fgneg jvgu gur anzrf bs Oebnqjnl zhfvpnyf rkprcg sbe gur ynfg jbeq; 6 (PNEOBA PBCL) znl fvzcyl or pbzcbhaq jbeqf, va juvpu pnfr gur bqq bar bhg vf gur sbhegu; 7 (PNEQVBVQ) nyy pbagnva n eha bs guerr pbafrphgvir ibjryf rkprcg sbe gur guveq; 9 (PBAFBYNGR) nccrnef gb or jbeqf gung ner nagbalzf bs gur jbeqf sbezrq ol chggvat gurve zbfg pbzzba cersvk va sebag bs gurz, rkprcg sbe gur guveq; 10 (QNTTRE) ner nyy glcbtencul flzobyf rkprcg sbe gur frpbaq...) (1/2)

Comment: rot13(...naq 13 (UVTUYVTUGRE) nccrne gb nyy pbagnva rknpgyl guerr bs bar yrggre rkprcg sbe gur ynfg. V fhfcrpg 12 (QVR) unf fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu cynpvat “va” fbzrjurer va gur jbeqf/cuenfrf, ohg V unira’g tbggra naljurer jvgu gung vqrn fb sne. Gur bgure gjb, 2 (NSGRERSSRPGF) naq 14 (YNOLEVAGUVAR), V unir ab fbyvq vqrnf lrg.) (2/2)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is:

> **CHINESE LANTERN**

First:

> In each group, one word is the odd one out because it doesn't fit a pattern that fits the other words.

AID AND ABET, CAT SCAN, HAIR TRIGGER, NINEVEH, SEES

> **SEES**, each word starts with a broadway musical, AIDA, CATS, HAIR, NINE (from @HTM)

AFTEREFFECTS, FREEZER, NOCUOUS, VERTEX, WARFARE

> **NOCUOUS**, each word can be typed with only the left hand on a keyboard (from @HTM)

ALUMINOSILICATES, BELOVED, HIMALAYAN, INDIA INK, VERISIMILITUDE

> **INDIA INK**, each word alternate vowels with consonants

ANTHERS, DOUGLASS, FIREBAR, SLUMBER, THOUSAND

> **ANTHERS**, each word has a construction material in its suffix, GLASS, REBAR, LUMBER, SAND

BATHROBE, BRAZEN, CAROUSEL, ELLIPSIS, WEIGHTIEST

> **ELLIPSIS**, take away first and last letters of each word to form a new word, ATHROB, RAZE, AROUSE, EIGHTIES

CARBON COPY, CROSSTALK, PENNY DREADFUL, TROUSERS, TURN UP

> **TROUSERS**, each phrase contains a word which clues a letter that starts the other word: CARBON = C (chemical symbol), CROSS = T (T-cross), PENNY = D (symbol for predecimal penny), TURN = U (U-turn) from (@Stiv)

CARDIOID, LINNAEAN, NICOTINIC, PALEOETHNOLOGY, TOE OF FROG

> **NICOTINIC**, each word contains an ABA vowel pattern, cardIOId, linnAEAn, palEOEthnology, tOE Of frog

COMMENCEMENT, DETOURS, JASMINE, JOINT HEIRS, THIS

> **COMMENCEMENT**, each word's suffix is a possessive, OURS, MINE, THEIRS, HIS

CONSOLATE, CORRIGIBLE, NEATH, SENSICAL, WHELMED

> **NEATH**, each word is normally used with a prefix that makes it the opposite, DISCONSOLATE, INCORRIGIBLE, NONSENSICAL, UNDERWHELMED

DAGGER, EVITATIVE, LOZENGE, PILCROW, TIE

> **EVITATIVE**, each word is a symbol

DEIFIED, KOOK, RIYAL ICON, PUT UP, RADAR

> **RIYAL ICON**, each word is a palindrome

DIE, ERT, GOOSE, SERAPH, SURGEON GENERAL

> **ERT**, each word is a singular whose plural is nonstandard, DICE, GEESE, SERAPHIM, SURGEONS GENERAL

HIGHLIGHTER, HOTHATCH, INDEPENDENT, PHENOMENON, SEVENTEENTH

> **HOTHATCH**, each word contains a repeated 3 letter pattern, IGH, NDE, ENO, ENT

LABYRINTHINE, MOTHY, PATHED, THINNER, UNTHINKABLE

> **LABYRINTHINE**, for each word, replacing the TH with an "S" sound makes a word: MOSSY, PASSED, SINNER, UNSINKABLE

Then:

> The odd words out each belong to 2 other groups (except for EVITATIVE which belongs to 3).  We can list these words in a cycle based on the 2 groups they belong to (from @hdsdv).  If we start with **COMMENCEMENT** (perhaps a hint as to where we should start), we get this:
>
>  **COMMENCEMENT** = Repeat 3 letters (MEN), Suffix building material (CEMENT)
>  **HOTHATCH** = Suffix building material (THATCH), Cryptic (HOT = H like on a faucet)
>  **INDIA INK** = Cryptic (India = I from NATO alphabet), ABA vowel pattern (IAI)
>  **NOCUOUS** = ABA vowel (UOU), Prefixed means opposite (INNOCUOUS)
>  **ERT** = Prefixed means opposite (INERT), Typed with left hand
>  **SEES** = Typed with left hand, Palindrome
>  **EVITATIVE** = Palindrome, Musical (EVITA)
>  **LABYRINTHINE** = Musical (LABYRINTH), Possessive suffix (THINE)
>  **ANTHERS** = Possessive suffix (HERS), Replace th with s sound (ANSWERS)
>  **NEATH** = Replace th with s sound (KNEES),  Remove first and last letter (EAT)
>  **TROUSERS** =  Remove first and last letter (ROUSER),  Irregular plural (TROUSERS)
>  **ELLIPSIS** = Irregular plural (ELLIPSES), Symbol
>  **RIYAL ICON** = Symbol, Alternating consonants/vowels
>  **NICOTONIC** = Alternating consonants/vowels, Repeat 3 letters (NIC)
>
>
>  Now, taking the first letter of each word, we get **CHINESE LANTERN**.

Comment: For 2, I think the pattern might be that rot13(nyy bs gur jbeqf pna or glcrq hfvat gur yrsg unaq ba n fgnaqneq xrlobneq rkprcg sbe gur guveq.) And for 13, rot13(gungpu vf n ohvyqvat zngrevny.)

Comment: Rather than rot13(pp jbeqf), is it possible that rot13(cnegf bs gurfr jbeqf pna or phg bhg naq pbzovarq jvgu "sver"? Guvf vf bayl cnegvny, ohg "pebffgnyx" lvryqf "pebffsver," "pneoba pbcl" lvryqf "obasver," "ghea hc" lvryqf "sver hea" (ovg bs n fgergpu), naq fb ba. Guvf pbhyq nyfb or n tebhc sbe "ubgungpu" fbzrubj.)

Comment: And rot13("ghea hc" lvryqf "sver hc")

Comment: rot13(Guvf frrzf yvxr zber bs n pbvapvqrapr guna nalguvat ryfr, ohg va gur GHEA HC tebhc, rnpu bgure jbeq pbagnvaf ng yrnfg guerr pbafrphgvir yrggref (NOP, EFG, QRS, EFGH). Bs gur bgure bqq-barf-bhg, NAGUREF naq PBZZRAPRZRAG funer guvf cebcregl.)

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, since I missed the edit window: rot13(V jnf pbaprearq gung gur pbafgehpgvba ehyr zvtug or gung vs n jbeq vf abg gur bqq-zna-bhg va vgf tebhc, gura vg pnaabg orybat gb nal bgure tebhc. Ohg CHG HC nygreangrf pbafbanagf naq ibjryf naq yrff pbaivapvatyl, GBRF BS SEBT.)

Comment: TROUSERS is not the answer to the puzzle. "Compound word" is not a correct grouping.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the CC thing", but none of the other ideas there are right either.

Comment: @js1 Nope, neither.

Comment: Worth noting is that, contrary to one of your assertions, rot13(GEBHFREF jvgubhg svefg naq ynfg yrggref vf “ebhfre”, bar jub ebhfrf bguref sebz fyrrc).

Comment: Added a hint for the CARBON COPY group!

Comment: For the CARBON COPY group, aside from TROUSERS rot13(rnpu pbagnva n jbeq gung pna or nooerivngrq gb n fvatyr yrggre: (P)NEOBA PBCL, PEBFF(K)GNYX, (C)RAAL QERNQSHY, GEBHFREF, GHEA (H)C. Va fbzr pnfrf gur yrggre rira eryngrf gb gur bgure unys (craal pna nyfb or Q - sbe Qernqshy - va cer-qrpvzny Ratyvfu zbarl, Pbcl ortvaf jvgu P, n G-pebff zvtug pbaarpg jvgu Gnyx, naq n H ghea...) ohg gung znl or ernqvat gbb zhpu vagb vg...)

Comment: @Stiv I don't think you're reading too much into it; I think your "stronger" version is exactly what is intended.

Comment: Perfectly! rot13(UBG pyhrf U (yvxr ba n gnc) juvpu ortvaf UNGPU, VAQVN pyhrf V (pbhagel nooerivngvba) juvpu ortvaf VAX. GHEA HC jbexf va gur tebhc orpnhfr GHEA pyhrf H juvpu ortvaf HC. CRAAL zhfg or gur Q yvxr V zragvba va zl bgure pbzzrag. Gura vg nyy jbexf!)

Comment: @Stiv That seems to be it, but I'm having a hard time seeing INDIA INK as having this property. Because rot13(V'z abg snzvyvne jvgu "V" nf na nooerivngvba sbe "Vaqvn", naq tbbtyvat qvqa'g vzzrqvngryl fubj zr bgurejvfr. Orfvqrf, vs GEBHFREF vf bayl tbvat gb unir bar cebcregl, qbrf VAQVN VAX ernyyl arrq gjb?)

Comment: oh, ignore above comment - NATO alphabet.

Comment: @Stiv OK I edited my answer to incorporate your theory, which looks good to me.  Now all I need is a theory on how to find the final answer!

Comment: If rot13(RIVGNGVIR qvq abg unir gur nygreangvat ibjryf naq pbafbanagf cebcregl, gur cnvevatf bs cebcregvrf sbe gur bqq-barf-bhg jbhyq sbez n fvzcyr plpyr), which is highly unlikely by random chance. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvKqL.png

Comment: If you see the initials, by the reverse order (still cyclic), I guess you will see the final answer : rot13(PUVARFR YNAGREA)

Comment: @athin Yes I just got it myself! A few days ago I ran the first letters through an anagrammer but the problem is that rot13(PUVARFR) wasn't in its dictionary (capital letter or something like that).  Anyways, the full solution is more elegant than just anagramming.

Comment: That's correct, nicely done!